# What causes control text to get cut off?

Tags: layout, text, vb6, dpi

My VB6 application is having a layout problem on certain end user PCs, but so far we are unable to identify what is causing this.

Normal layout: [image]

Broken layout: [image]

The text on the left are the captions of the radio buttons. The text in the upper right is a label.

I am familiar with two different settings in Windows Control Panel which can affect text size, and initially we suspected this was the cause. In Windows 10, they are:

```
 Control Panel >
  Appearance and Personalization >
   Display >
    (1) "Use these display settings" > "Customize your display"
             or
    (2) "Set a custom scaling level"
```

(Terminology was different in earlier Windows versions but I think the features were the same?)

However upon testing these settings with our app *neither reproduces the problem*.

**What else might be causing the text layout issue shown in the image?**

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be caused by [a Windows bug](http://www.rlvision.com/misc/windows_7_font_bug.asp).

The description & fix as mentioned in the source website are as follows:

> if you have a high resolution screen at install time, Win7 will install a larger font set (125%) by default. If you then choose go back to the standard font size (100%), Windows will keep some of the large fonts even though everything else is adjusted for standard fonts, **causing programs that use these fonts to break** because the text will not always fit inside the GUI.
>
> By editing the Windows registry you can get the original, intended fonts back:
>
> - Open the start menu and type regedit and then press Enter.
> - Locate the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`
> - Find the value `MS Sans Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24`
> - Change from `SSERIFF.FON` to `SSERIFE.FON`
> - Find `MS Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24`
> - Change from `SERIFF.FON` to `SERIFE.FON`
> - Finally find `Courier 10,12,15`
> - Change from `COURF.FON` to `COURE.FON`
> - Restart your system in order for the changes to take effect!
>
> The exact font names may vary depending on locale settings.

I was able to create the problem scenario as described here on Windows 10, and that reproduced the problem with our VB6 app. I think that confirms this as the fix.

A [Microsoft blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/developingfordynamicsgp/2009/11/24/windows-7-bitmap-fonts-and-microsoft-dynamics-gp/) seems to be the authoritative original source of this information.